# How to visualize the results of a method which predicts binned probabilities?

Tags: machine-learning, data-visualization

I'm attempting to create a machine learning model that predicts some real-valued data points.

If I was using a straight regression approach (that is, one where the output is a real-valued number), I would know how to visualize it. For example, I could use a scatter plot of predictions versus known. Or I could take the residuals and plot them against some other value, either as a scatter plot for continuous data, or as a violin plot for categorical. There are a number of options, and standard plotting tools are well set up for this sort of `N x 1` against `N x 1` plotting.

However, some of the models I'm trying don't predict the real-valued output directly, but rather do binned probability prediction -- that is, they predict the probability the value is within a particular sub-range for a discrete set of sub-ranges. (Or technically, they predict logits for each bin which can be easily converted to probabilities with a softmax function.)

I'm not sure how to handle this data for visualization, given that there isn't a single number per input, but rather `Nbins` of them, and the data is not a direct value, but rather a binned probability distribution. I guess I could imagine some sort of heatmap, perhaps, but I'm not sure if that would be useful in practice, or how one might go about actually creating something like that from the inputs.

As I understand it, this sort of binned prediction is a standard approach in machine learning. Are there standard methods people use to visualize the outputs? What sort of plots are common for this sort of thing? Also, are there standard (preferably Python) tools for converting an `N x Nbins` array of binned probabilities and an associated `N x 1` array of abscissa values into such a figure?

Comment: 1) Isn’t that an ordinal regression? 2) Why don’t you have access to the original data before it got stuck in bins? Yes, sometimes we’re stuck with with what we’re stuck with, but if there is a way to access the unbinned data, it is worth exploring.

Comment: @Dave There are no "before binning" predictions. The model directly outputs the probability for each bin. Effectively, you have `Nbins` separate binary classifiers which are being trained on (e.g.) "is the output between 2.5 and 3.0?" -- So instead of having the model producing a single real-valued output which you subsequently segment into distinct groups to predict intrinsically discretized knowns (as you would with ordinal regression), the knowns you're trying to predict are continuous reals, which for ease of modeling you artificially discretize and train multiple joint classifiers on.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a great way to model such data.  It seems closer to multinomial logistic regression than ordinal LR.  It might be better to just scrap it and go with a more conventional approach.  Regarding this question, could you paste in a sample dataset for people to work with?